# How to prevent "regex injection"?

Tags: c#, regex, user-input, code-injection, sanitization

How to prevent something I'd call "regex injection"?

I'm using regular expressions to parse strings that might look like - one of the examples -

> **Size:** 10, **qty:** 20

Writing a regex to capture "10" and "20" is not hard by itself.
"Size" and "qty" are, however, customizable - user can choose some other words instead.

So what I do is:

```
var pattern = String.Format(
                    @"{0}[ \t]*(?<size>{1}|\d*)[ \t]*:[ \t]*{2}:[ \t]*(?<quantity>[\d]*)",
                    sizeSign,
                    univerSizeAbbrev,
                    qtySign);
```

But how do I 'sanitize' sizeSign, qtySign (or univerSizeAbbrev for that matter)?

Regex does not have procedure parameters like SQL does (?), so how do I make sure, positively sure that **sizeSign** and **qtySign** are always treated as literals, whatever they are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you include:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

And then escape the variables like this:

```
sizeSign = Regex.Escape(sizeSign);
qtySign = Regex.Escape(qtySign);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to assume that the identifiers can only consist of letter characters, this becomes easy. Just test each with

```
str.Any(ch => ! Char.IsLetter(ch));
```

and reject any choices for which this returns false.